# How to make a dynamic Picker using React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make a `Picker` dynamic. They are 02 *Pickers* and the second options appear according to the option selected in the first *Picker*.

When I select the first *Picker*, I get the error `Cannot read 'props' of null`.

The code and more explanation is in [this repository](https://github.com/danielfeelfine/react-native-picker).

I also open this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12829#issuecomment-285381205) in React Native repository on Github.